# CS50 - C -problemset 2 - substitution - output not valid ASCII text - KEY: yukfrnlbavmwzteogxhcipjsqd

Tags: c, encryption, cs50

Finished my code and ran the tests to check if my solution is correct.
While running the tests I got many bugs, fixed them and found a solution but I'm stuck at this tests.

---

The keys used are:

yukfrnlbavmwzteogxhcipjsqd

YUKFRNLBAVMWZteogxhcipjsqd

---

Not sure why it's not mapping correctly to the ASCII values.

---

Errors:

```
:( encrypts "This is CS50" as "Cbah ah KH50" using yukfrnlbavmwzteogxhcipjsqd as key
Cause
output not valid ASCII text
Log
running ./substitution yukfrnlbavmwzteogxhcipjsqd...
sending input This is CS50...
checking for output "ciphertext: Cbah ah KH50\n"...
```

Failed this two tests:

```
:( encrypts "This is CS50" as "Cbah ah KH50" using YUKFRNLBAVMWZteogxhcipjsqd as key
Cause
output not valid ASCII text
Log
running ./substitution YUKFRNLBAVMWZteogxhcipjsqd...
sending input This is CS50...
checking for output "ciphertext: Cbah ah KH50\n"...
```

---

Heres my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int encipher(string KEY, string PLAINTEXT);

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    // Initialize KEY constant
    string KEY = argv[1];
    // Initialize length constant
    int len = 26;

    // Check for missing command-line argument
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Check for KEY length
    if (strlen(KEY) != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Check for non alphabetic characters & repeated characters
    // Initialize character variable
    char c;
    // Check for non alphabetic characters cycle
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        // Assign character value
        c = KEY[i];
        // Checking for non alphabetic characters
        if (!isalpha(c))
        {
            printf("Key must contain only alphabetic characters.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    // Repeated characters
    for (int j = 0; j < len; j++)
    {
        // j + 1 is used to advance one position
        for (int k = j+1; k < len; k++)
        {
            // Comparing KEY position
            if (toupper(KEY[j]) == toupper(KEY[k]))
            {
                printf("Key must not contain repeated characters.\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    // Ask user for plaintext constant
    string PLAINTEXT = get_string("plaintext: ");

    // call Encipher fucntion
    encipher(KEY, PLAINTEXT);

    return 0;
}

int encipher(string KEY, string PLAINTEXT)
{
    // Initialize PLAINTEXT length constant
    int l = strlen(PLAINTEXT);
    // Print encipher text
    printf("ciphertext: ");

    // Convert to uppercase KEY characters
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        if (islower(KEY[i]))
        {
            KEY[i] = KEY[i] - 32;
        }
    }

    // Cycle in PLAINTEXT to map each character to the KEY
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        // Check if PLAINTEXT[i] is uppercase
        if (isupper(PLAINTEXT[i]))
        {
            // Int is used to acces the ASCII values
            int character = PLAINTEXT[i] - 65;
            printf("%c", KEY[character]);
        }
        // Check if PLAINTEXT[i] is lowercase
        else if (islower(PLAINTEXT[i]))
        {
            // Int is used to acces the ASCII values
            int character = PLAINTEXT[i] - 97;
            // + 32 to select the lower case ASCII values
            printf("%c", KEY[character] + 32);
        }
        // If the KEY is the same as the alphabet print the ciphertext
        else printf("%c", PLAINTEXT[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: Why not pre-compute a mapping table for all possible ASCII values, then apply that without all the `if` stuff clouding your logic? You can easily verify the table is correct, then any problems must occur with applying it, which is a much smaller scope.

Comment: Tip: Try and avoid *magical* numbers. Instead of `97` and `65` use `'a'` and `'A'` respectively. Instead of `+ 32` you could use `x & 0x20` or `x | 0x20` to make it clear you're effectively flipping a bit, if not just use `tolower()` on everything anyway, forget the `if`, as the cost of applying that is virtually the same as the test to see if it's uppercase.

Comment: @tadman Alterative to `+ 32, & 0x20, | 0x20, ...` and other magic numbers: Flip the case bit with `KEY[i]  ^= 'A' ^ 'a';`.  No magic numbers:  works with ASCII and [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC).  Of course, `toupper()` is best practice.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica EBCDIC compatibility is something I always appreciate in a solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
{
    if (islower(KEY[i]))
    {
        KEY[i] = KEY[i] - 32;
    }
}
```

This converts *the first `l` characters* of the key to upper case, using the caveman's method.

```
printf("%c", KEY[character] + 32);
```

This converts a character of the key to lower case using the caveman's method --- and the caveman's method requires that the source character is in the upper case. However you failed to convert *all* the characters of the key to the upper case, you only converted the first few.

The proper way to convert between the cases are `toupper` and `tolower` functions.

Comment: To avoid magic numbers like 32, could use `KEY[i] ^ 'A' ^ 'a'` to flip the case bit.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica that's assuming there *is* a case bit.

Comment: Of course `to...()` is best practice, yet encodings of A-z, a-z overwhelming do use one bit to flip the case.   Better than magic number 32, which relies on more assumptions.